# How to create a function to delete element by element?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, gradient

I am creating a gradient editor in JavaScript, I have already created the function to add colors, but I can not make the function to remove color, the idea is that when the visitor right click on the color selector (`<input type="color">`) shows a submenu with the option to remove the color.

But the more that I have tried I could not achieve that when giving right click the submenu corresponding to the selector is shown and that in the button comes out the corresponding function to eliminate this selector.

Here is my reduced html:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('grContainer');
var endValueIn = document.getElementById('endGrValue');
var grType = document.getElementById('typeGrSel');
var dirGrSelA = document.getElementById('dirGrSelA');
var BtnCreate = document.getElementById('BtnCreate');
var colors = document.querySelectorAll(".color");
var count = 1;
var containe = document.getElementById('Containerdp');

function addColoru() {
  count = count + 1;
  var newColor = document.createElement('input');
  newColor.className = `form-control form-control-color color colao-${count}`;
  newColor.setAttribute('type', 'color');
  newColor.setAttribute('oncontextmenu', 'contextMenu()');
  container.appendChild(newColor);
  var newBtn = document.createElement('div');
  newBtn.id = 'remConBtn';
  newBtn.className = `btnc-${count} remConBtn`;
  newBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  newBtn.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'dropdown');
  newBtn.setAttribute('data-bs-auto-close', 'true');
  newBtn.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
  newBtn.innerHTML = '|';
  containe.appendChild(newBtn);
  var newUl = document.createElement('ul');
  newUl.id = 'remConMen';
  newUl.className = `dropdown-menu dmnc-${count}`;
  containe.appendChild(newUl);
  var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newUl.appendChild(newLi);
  var newA = document.createElement('a');
  newA.className = 'dropdown-item text-danger';
  newA.innerHTML = '<i class="bi bi-trash3"></i> Eliminar';
  newLi.appendChild(newA);
}

function contextMenu() {
  var remConBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.remConBtn');
  var inuu = 0;
  var lengthww = remConBtn.length;
  for (; inuu < lengthww; inuu++) {
    remConBtn[inuu].click();
  }
}
```

```css
#remConBtn {
  top: -38px;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: -100;
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="input-group" id="grContainer" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <input class="form-control form-control-color color colao-1" oncontextmenu="contextMenu()" type="color" />
</div>
<div id="Containerdp">
  <div id="remConBtn" class="btnc-1 remConBtn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="true" aria-expanded="false">
    |
  </div>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dmnc-1" id="remConMen">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-danger"><i class="bi bi-trash3"></i> Delete</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="BtnCreate" onclick="addColoru()"><i class="bi bi-plus" style="font-size: 30px"></i></div>
```

Complete version on CodePen: https://codepen.io/Puma-Murca/pen/bGZGKEp

Note: I am using an external library (Bootstrap) so I don't need questions with the use of JQuery

Comment: I suggest you delegate clicks from nearest static container. I also suggest you use data-attributes to identify the colorID